# Is there a way to run clickhouse in m1 chip based mac's?

Tags: database, macos, docker, clickhouse, apple-m1

UNSUPPORTED PLATFORM:

[image]

I've tried to install clickhouse in m1 chip.

Comment: Looks like it's not supported yet: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/20245

Comment: Why does it say (linux/arm64)? I thought you were trying to install it on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

work fine for me on m1 pro 2021:

docker-compose.yml

```
clickhouse:
      image: lunalabsltd/clickhouse-server:21.7.2.7-arm
      container_name: "clickhouse"
      ports:
        - 8123:8123
      environment:
        - CLICKHOUSE_DB=testing
        - CLICKHOUSE_USER=default
        - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=default
```

Comment: It can be a good idea to add `- ./clickhouse-data:/var/lib/clickhouse` in `volumes`

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `mac` on their various communities turns up nothing. If you don't get a response maybe you need to make a request on github. Did you try `yarn remove clickhouse`? Don't have M1, so can't try